# Ribbon timeout on Zuul API Gateway for route

Tags: java, netflix-zuul, hystrix, api-gateway, netflix-ribbon

I have microservices with Zuul API Gateway. For discovery service I use Zookeeper.

In Zuul, I've set many routes for a single service, for example:

```
zuul:  
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    customer:
      path: /customers/**
      serviceId: CustomerService
      stripPrefix: false
    customerAsync:
      path: /async/customers/**
      serviceId: CustomerService
      stripPrefix: false
```

I know how set ribbon timeout for serviceId:

```
CustomerService:
    ribbon:
        ReadTimeout: 20000
```

But is possible set ribbon timeout for route name? For example:

```
customerAsync:
    ribbon:
        ReadTimeout: 20000
```

Hystrix isolation strategy in hystrix default is SEMAPHORE. Should I change it to THREAD and set timeout for single command?

What is your experience with timeout operation on zuul?

Comment: Did you find solution ?